# My Android Application based on the following ActionBar tutorial is encountering fatal error and stopping unexpectedly.

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, adb

The tutorial:
http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs

My "ClosetActivity" which is basically my main activity:

```
package ootd.com;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 *
 * @author Michelle
 */
public class ClosetActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    //Declare tabs in action bar
    ActionBar.Tab userTab, closetTab, garmentTab, createGarmentTab;
    //instantiate Tab classes
    Fragment fragmentUser = new UserTab();
    Fragment fragmentCloset = new ClosetTab();
    Fragment fragmentGarment = new GarmentTab();
    Fragment fragmentCreateGarment = new CreateGarmentTab();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //action bar tab indicators
        userTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("You");
        closetTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Your Closets");
        garmentTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Your Clothes");
        createGarmentTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Add Garments");

        userTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentUser));
        closetTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentCloset));
        garmentTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentGarment));
        createGarmentTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentCreateGarment));

        actionBar.addTab(userTab);
        actionBar.addTab(closetTab);
        actionBar.addTab(garmentTab);
        actionBar.addTab(createGarmentTab);
    }
}
```

Commenting everything below the line
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

allows the app to at least sit in the mainactivity state, without "stopping unexpectedly".

This is one of my "Tab" classes aka "GarmentTab.java":

```
package ootd.com;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Fragment;
/**
 *
 * @author Michelle
 */
public class GarmentTab extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_tab, container, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.tabtextview);
        textview.setText(R.string.Garment);
        return inflaterView;
    }   
}
```

This is "MyTabListener.java" class:

```
package ootd.com;
import android.app.*;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
/**
 *
 * @author Michelle
 */
public class MyTabListener implements TabListener {
    Fragment fragment;

    //Constructor passes in and sets "fragment" fragment
    public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    //Passes in "ft" FragmentTransaction
        ///and replaces this.fragment with  R.id."fragment_container"
        ///using ft.replace
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }    
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
}
```

This is my "main.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And this is my "test_tab.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabtextview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally adbLog:

```
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Process: ootd.com, PID: 21140
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ootd.com/ootd.com.ClosetActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at ootd.com.ClosetActivity.onCreate(ClosetActivity.java:37)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
17:32:01.476    21140   ootd.com    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
```

Comment: What is your line 37 of ClosetActivity.java? Your app is crashing there.

Comment: In which API level are you testing your code?

Comment: Hmm yeah line 37 is causing the error in ClosetActivity.java I think you should move your intialization of your fragments into onCreate instead of above it as well. Just a convention...

Comment: also make sure your targeting honeycomb and later! Fragment as apposed to v4.Fragment is only available in honeycomb and later

Comment: My testing device is running 4.4.2. My code targets 4.4W. I don't see how this could be an issue because I have other applications that target 4.4W that run without crashing on this device.  I moved my init of fragments into onCreate. It's not working, and I don't know what the error is on line 37, netbeans doesn't show a problem with it.

Comment: I'm seeing other issues with this actionbar function...I just haven't found one that fixes my problem yet..

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, so there were multiple problems.
Apparently you need to getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) before setting any content with the new action bar api since honeycomb. Not only that but as this blog pointed out, http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html there's this crappy design flaw where your action bar implementation is linked to your app visual theme... o.0 If I don't set the theme the action bar's broken. Lastly I didn't actually set the minsdkversion in the activitymanifest, it was targeting 4.4W in project properties. Apparently that's not enough. The edited files look like this now:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ootd.com"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/> 
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity android:name="ClosetActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ClosetActivity:

```
public class ClosetActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here 
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //Declare tabs in action bar
        ActionBar.Tab userTab, closetTab, garmentTab, createGarmentTab;

        //instantiate Tab classes
        Fragment fragmentUser = new UserTab();
        Fragment fragmentCloset = new ClosetTab();
        Fragment fragmentGarment = new GarmentTab();
        Fragment fragmentCreateGarment = new CreateGarmentTab();



        //action bar tab indicators
        userTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("You");
        closetTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Your Closets");
        garmentTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Your Clothes");
        createGarmentTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Add Garments");

        userTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentUser));
        closetTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentCloset));
        garmentTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentGarment));
        createGarmentTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentCreateGarment));

        actionBar.addTab(userTab);
        actionBar.addTab(closetTab);
        actionBar.addTab(garmentTab);
        actionBar.addTab(createGarmentTab);
    }
//http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs
}
```